# I want to sort the Mongodb data based on Array size

Tags: java, database, mongodb, spring-data, mongotemplate

I'm having student (String) and instructor (List of String).I want to fetch the record based on the instructor count in Descending order. instructor as below
Sample:   [a,b,c] -3, [e,f] -2, [g,h,i,j] -4.

I want in the order of 4 and 3 and then 2.

That is based on the field instructor array's size.How to query this using mongoTemplate or custom mongodb query or aggregation??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to sort by array size from mongodb.
Aggregation for the above is:

newAggregation(addFields().addField("nInstructors")
.withValue(new Document ("$size, "nInstructors")).build(),
sort(DESC, "nInstructors"),
limit(limitCount)
);

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- add a new field with the `$size` of the instructor array
- sort descending by that field
- unset that field

*sort doesn't accept an expression we couldn't do it in 1 stage without adding a new field.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70621615-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":{"nInstructors":{"$size":"$instructor"}}},
 {"$sort":{"nInstructors":-1}},
 {"$unset":["nInstructors"]}])
```

Query2

- same as above but checks if array first, to avoid errors if field has other type or missing.

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70621615-1-m)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set":
  {"nInstructors":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$isArray":["$instructor"]}, {"$size":"$instructor"}, 0]}}},
 {"$sort":{"nInstructors":-1}},
 {"$unset":["nInstructors"]}])
```

Comment: But unfortunately in my project, I couldn't use "$size".If I use it, then it's saying 'size requires number' runtime error. I have seen somewhere,some version of mongo Don't allow the "$size" in query for array.

Comment: `$size` is so old operator from mongodb 2.6 we are MongoDB 5 now, so its not your version i guess, i think in your collection the field has in some documents other types and $size doesn't work (for example null or missing etc). i added one more query i think it will be ok

Comment: I tried with above Query..this time it's saying "unrecognized pipeline stage name : '$set' ".. I'm using in the way of @Aggregation("{query in ' single quotes(replace all double with single quote)}")

Comment: try to replace `$set` with `$addFields`  (they do the same, you have older version of mongodb)

Comment: It's working fine in robo3t mongo query with db.getcollection(collecName).aggregate({query}).But in the case of @Aggregation({query}) I'm passing the same query..But it's returning documents in the same database stored order. How to add the same in correct way for @Aggregation

Comment: i dont know what driver you use, see the driver documentation on how to call an aggregation, it will be very simple, just need the syntax. In java its called aggregate, the method of collection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Takis_ for your help